# Opsworks : cron : Ruby version is incorrect

Tags: ruby, cron, aws-opsworks

My objective is to setup a cron entry to run a rake task on my Opsworks rails application layer. 
I have followed the [AWS doco on this subject found here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-cron.html)

**My Chef Job:**

```
cron_env = {"PATH" => "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"}
cron "warm up the cache" do
  environment cron_env
  hour "5"
  minute "10"
  command "cd /srv/www/myapp/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake cache:warm_api"
end
```

**The crontab on the instance:**

```
user@myinstance:~$ sudo crontab -l -u root
# Chef Name: warm up the cache
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
10 5 * * * cd /srv/www/myapp/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake cache:warm_api
```

**My ruby -v in /usr/local/bin:**

```
user@myinstance:~$ /usr/local/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

During execution, my cron fails to use the correct ruby.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:385:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:117:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be temporary glitch in Opsworks.